# How can I prevent anything from happening when I shut the lid of my laptop?

Tags: server, laptop, suspend, acpi

I have a laptop running 12.04 Server Edition, and I'd like to be able to shut the lid without anything happening.

I need it to remain `ping`able and `ssh`able and continue to run all of its daemons and everything after the lid is closed.

Remember, no GUI conf utilities, because this is server edition, with no X server installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Put `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` under `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

[image]

You have to restart systemd daemon with `restart systemd-logind` or restart your laptop.